# Importing OribitControls doesn't work with error in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working in localhost, I tried to import "orbitcontrols()" but somehow it doesn't work and show error.
[The error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NZZK.png)

`main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at main.js:1:1)`

and this is how i imported the orbitcontrols() in my main.js

```
import {OrbitControls} from "./examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

//...there are scene, camera and renderer etc

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera,canvas)
controls.enableDamping = true 

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    controls.update();

    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
    renderer.render(scene,camera);

}
animate()
```

and this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>만들어보아요.01</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
        <script src="./three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my folder

[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCFPV.png)

```
someFolder
 | 
 ├ -index.html
 ├ -main.js
 ├ -three.min.js
 ├ -style.css
 ├ -package-lock.json
 |
 ├ -build
 | |
 | +-three.module.js
 |
 +-examples
   |
   +-jsm
     |
     +-controls
       |
       +-OrbitControls.js
      

     ...
```

may be i used 'three.min.js' file instead 'three.js'?

I would be appreciate so much, if anyone give advice me .

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `type` of the `script` as `module`, like:

```
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: I tried that but there are other error ,"Access to script at 'file:///Users/taeyuan/mine/three/02/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https." ㅠㅠ but thank your advice! :)

Comment: @TaeYu Browsers don't allow websites to access local files from a website for security.

Comment: Make sure the JavaScript file is hosted on a server, not on your computer.

Comment: @Vivaan  Thanks ! I'm a newbie , so i didn't know that Browser don't allow , But, Now i know if i want use THEE(any Js library) , I need a Bundler Tool like 'webpack' , Again thank you guys~ !>~<